# Using NPM & gruntjs build system

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to Node.js echo system and trying to set up a build system for JavaScript application development. I have some questions that I can't find answers to.

From [this blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/), it is clear that you should install all the project specific node modules locally.

Now, I am installing the entire `grunt` module locally in my project directory. I get the following directory structure...

```
my_project/

  lib/
    utils/
      underscore.js

  ... other project files ...

  node_modules/
    .bin/
      grunt -> ../grunt/bin/grunt*
    grunt/
      node_modules/
      bin/
      dev/
      docs/
      lib/
      test/
      tasks/
      grunt.js
      package.json
      ... others ...
```

Note that there are TWO `node_modules` directories. One in my project and other inside the `grunt` module.

**Q**: Why are there multiple `node_modules` directories at different levels? Can someone explain me how the directory structure works?

**Q**: If I install another module, will it also have its own `node_modules` directory?

**Q**: If I go within `my_project/lib/utils` and then run the command `npm install <some_module>`, will that module be installed only for that directory or for the entire project? If the latter, then how does NPM/Node figure out the project root?

Please explain anything else I might be missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Every project in the npm registry can be thought of a self-contained module (specifically, a CommonJS module) that has source code and project metadata defined in a `package.json` file in the root directory of that project.

When you type `npm install` (or just `npm i`) in a directory with a `package.json` file, npm reads the collection of `dependencies` defined in `package.json` in your project's root directory and installs those packages in the `node_modules` directory.

So what's with the nested `node_modules` directories? `npm install` is recursive. If project A requires B and B requires C, you'd see this directory structure:

```
A/
A/node_modules
A/node_modules/B
A/node_modules/B/node_modules
A/node_modules/B/node_modules/C
```

In your case, when you add `grunt` to `dependencies` in the `my_project/package.json` file, that dependency will get added to its own directory: `my_project/node_modules/grunt`. But `grunt` has a lot of dependencies, and those dependencies have dependencies. So you'll see many nested `node_modules` directories.

For your third question, see the `algorithm` section on this page: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html -- it describes how `npm install` searches for dependencies.

There's also some more information about global vs local dependencies in npm [here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).